# Change branch for latest version

Tags: read-the-docs

I have a new ReadTheDocs installation where the 'latest' version points to the 'master' branch of my GitHub repository. I would like to change the branch to 'development' but have found nothing in the documentation that tells me how to do it. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that the necessary setting is in Admin->Advanced Settings, not in Admin->Versions as I would have expected.

Comment: For what is worth, I tried this now in 09/22 and it's still under "Admin -> Advanced Settings", work like a charm. Thanks Jonathan!

Comment: in 2024, it is now directly in settings, as "Default branch"